# Mysql: Get next and previous in duplicated records

Tags: mysql, performance

My database has two columns ID and Timestamp.

```
4  1597228600
8  1597228700
12 1597228700
11 1597228800
14 1597228800
9  1597228900
10 1597228900
1  1597228900
2  1597229000
```

I need to get next (previous) record of the given id and timestamp ordered by timestamp. If the timestamp has duplicates, the record with higher(lower) id should be returned.

In the example Next and Prev records of the 11(1597228800) are 14 and 12. Next and Prev records of the 14(1597228800) are 1 and 11.

I tried to use CASE condition with subquery, but this solution  has issues

```
SELECT id 
FROM tbl 
WHERE timestamp_value >= '1597228800' 
AND id > (case when ( SELECT min(id) min_id FROM tbl WHERE id > 11 AND timestamp_value = 1597228800) is null then 0 else 11 end) 
ORDER BY timestamp_value
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: 14 is the next record of the 11. 
Explanation: The 14 and 11 records have the same timestamp, so the record with higher id with the same timestamps is the next, which is 14 in the current example.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: MySQL version is 5.7

Comment: So if all time stamps were equal, then we'd simply be sorting by id?

Comment: @Strawberry yes. But in the example some records with lower ID has higher Timestamp, so I can't use ID as second argument in the ORDER BY statement.

Comment: ??? Why not ???

Comment: @Strawberry I mean it's not enough to use ID as a second argument. 
"SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE timestamp >= 1597228800 ORDER BY timestamp DESC, id ASC" returns 12, but the correct result is 1.

Comment: So you want 2 rows in the  results?

Comment: @forpas for now only "next" record is enough. It's ok for me to have two different queries for next and prev records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this will do:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t 
cross join (select * from tablename where id = ?) i
where t.id in (
  (
    select id from tablename 
    where (id < i.id and timestamp = i.timestamp) or timestamp < i.timestamp
    order by timestamp desc, id desc limit 1
  ),  
  (
    select id from tablename 
    where (id > i.id and timestamp = i.timestamp) or timestamp > i.timestamp
    order by timestamp, id limit 1
  ) 
)
```

Replace `?` with the `id` that you want to search for.
The 2 subqueries return the ids of the previous and the next id of `?`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=70b68258131d4fdcd56c895d61af1017).